# Unity 5 "Build & Install iPhone player" dialog does not disappear

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, build

i have a critical problem. When i build my game for iOS everything seems to work. Xcode pops up and i can start deploying on a iDevice. But when i go back to Unity the "Build & Install iPhone player" Dialog is still there and I have to kill Unity and restart it to go on.

[image]

Any ideas whats going on?

thanks,
Stephan

Comment: what's your unity version ?
OS ?

Comment: Unity 5.4.1f1 on Mac OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Upgrade to 5.4.1 latest patch and try....

Comment: This is the latest version for Unity on Mac OS. This problem came with this update. My earlier version was 5.3.x and everything was fine.

Comment: Actually unity 5.4.2 is out. They fixed numerous bugs in this version. I am using 5.4.1p2 and I never had any problems.... Anyway better upgrade to 5.4.2 and try

Comment: ah ok, why does Unitys "check for updates" don't show me 5.4.2.? I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: may be installation got corrupted, that may be the reason you are seeing weird behaviour

Comment: @Arun finaly with version 5.4.2 everything works like expected. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125709/discussion-between-arun-and-sight).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually unity 5.4.2 is out. They fixed numerous bugs in this version. I am using 5.4.1p2 and I never had any problems.... Anyway better upgrade to 5.4.2 and try